# Почему GetTempPathA возвращает крякообразные символы

Tags: c++, winapi

Я написал функцию для получения папки %Temp%

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char* path = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,MAX_PATH + 1)
    DWORD tempLenght = GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH + 1,path);
    std::cout << path;
}
```

Но вывод

```
C:\Users\CAC0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Имя пользователя было установлено кирилицей из-за этого ломается вывод но почему если я установил `setlocale`?

Так-же пытался использовать вместо `char` - `wchar_t` и `GetTempPath` но от этого программа вылетает после запуска

Comment: А если setlocale() заменить на SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)? К слову, по этой причине никогда не следует задавать имя пользователя кириллицей - некоторые программы из-за этого банально не работают (сам с этим сталкивался).

Comment: @LShadow77 Всё так-же C:\Users\CAC0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\, я понимаю что имя пользователя кирилицей проблема но почему тогда `SHGetFolderPathA()` выводит нормально а `GetTempPathA()` криво?

Comment: Возможно, Вам поможет это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129686/gettemppatha-returning-incorrect-user-folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в консоли выводится короткое имя пути (поподробней можете почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129686/gettemppatha-returning-incorrect-user-folder).

Попробуйте воспользоваться функцией `GetLongPathNameA`, которая конвертирует короткую форму в полную. ([MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamea))

Пример использования:

```
char* path = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, MAX_PATH + 1);
DWORD tempLenght = GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH + 1, path);
char long_path[MAX_PATH + 1];
DWORD temp = GetLongPathNameA(path, long_path, MAX_PATH + 1);
std::cout << path << endl << long_path << endl;
```

Comment: Вывод тот-ж C:\Users\CAC0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: @Arhip_Smirnov может код, который [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322442/getting-user-temporary-folder-path-in-windows) поможет вам

Comment: @Arhip_Smirnov я подправил ответ, может сейчас он вам поможет